# install gstat on r 3.0.3 for mac

Tags: r, macos, gstat

I have Mac OS Yosemite and R 3.0.3. I really need to install the gstat package, but I keep getting this message:

```
install.packages("gstat")
trying URL 'http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/gstat_1.0-19.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2167243 bytes (2.1 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 Mb


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/qh/lzjfx8v52vz1k09v5svctxc80000gn/T//Rtmpm2gfwv/downloaded_packages
```

Answer (score 0):

CRAN supports `Snow Leopard` and `Mavericks` binaries; up to a while ago many packages depending on `rgeos`, including `gstat`, were not available for `Mavericks`. This has been resolved now for `gstat` (though not for `rgeos`).